A Java class for checking whether a white king is under checkmate
(I have this chess engine in Java; under construction.)
This post presents my logic for investigating whether the white king is in checkmate.
com.github.coderodde.game.chess.impl.WhiteCheckMateInspector.java
package com.github.coderodde.game.chess.impl;

import com.github.coderodde.game.chess.CellCoordinates;
import com.github.coderodde.game.chess.CheckMateInspector;
import com.github.coderodde.game.chess.ChessBoardState;
import static com.github.coderodde.game.chess.ChessBoardState.N;
import com.github.coderodde.game.chess.Piece;
import com.github.coderodde.game.chess.impl.attackcheck.WhiteUnderAttackCheck;
import com.github.coderodde.game.chess.UnderAttackCheck;
import com.github.coderodde.game.chess.impl.attackcheck.BlackUnderAttackCheck;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class implements the API for checking for checkmate for the white king.
 * 
 * @version 1.0.1 (Jul 28, 2024)
 * @since 1.0.0 (Jul 16, 2024)
 */
public final class WhiteCheckMateInspector implements CheckMateInspector {
    
    private static final int ATTACKER_CELLS_LENGTH = 8;
    private static final CellCoordinates[] ATTACKER_CELLS = 
            new CellCoordinates[ATTACKER_CELLS_LENGTH];
    
    private static final UnderAttackCheck WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER = 
            new WhiteUnderAttackCheck();
    
    private static final UnderAttackCheck BLACK_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER = 
            new BlackUnderAttackCheck();

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < ATTACKER_CELLS.length; i++) {
            ATTACKER_CELLS[i] = new CellCoordinates();
        }
    }
    
    private int attackerCellsSize;
    
    /**
     * This method is responsible of finding out whether there is a checkmate 
     * for the white player.
     * 
     * @param state the state to check.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the input state is in checkmate for
     *         the white player.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isInCheckMate(final ChessBoardState state) {
    
        final int kingFile = state.getWhiteKingFile();
        final int kingRank = state.getWhiteKingRank();
        
        if (WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(state, 
                                                   kingFile, 
                                                   kingRank) == false) {
            // Easy case: the white king is not under attack.
            return false;
        }
        
        attackerCellsSize = 0;
        
        if (canHideWest(state, kingFile, kingRank)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (canHideEast(state, kingFile, kingRank)) {
            return false;
        }
            
        if (canHideNorth(state, kingFile, kingRank)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (canHideNorthWest(state, kingFile, kingRank)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (canHideNorthEast(state, kingFile, kingRank)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (canHideSouth(state, kingFile, kingRank)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (canHideSouthWest(state, kingFile, kingRank)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (canHideSouthEast(state, kingFile, kingRank)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        Arrays.sort(ATTACKER_CELLS, 0, attackerCellsSize);
        
        if (ATTACKER_CELLS[0].equals(ATTACKER_CELLS[attackerCellsSize - 1])) {
            return cannotDefend(state);
        }
        
        // Once here, we have more than one offending black pieces. Since we can
        // hope to eliminate at most one of them, the game is lost for the white
        // player and we have a checkmate:
        return true;
    }
    
    private static boolean cannotDefend(final ChessBoardState state) {
        final CellCoordinates attackerCellCoordinates = ATTACKER_CELLS[0];
        
        return !BLACK_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(
                state, 
                attackerCellCoordinates.file, 
                attackerCellCoordinates.rank);
    }
    
    /**
     * Tries to hide the white king to the north (towards the smaller rank
     * index).
     * 
     * @param state    the state to investigate.
     * @param kingFile the file of the white king.
     * @param kingRank the rank of the white king.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the white king can hide to north.
     */
    private boolean canHideNorth(final ChessBoardState state, 
                                 final int kingFile, 
                                 final int kingRank) {
        if (kingRank == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final Piece northPiece = state.get(kingFile,
                                           kingRank - 1);
        
        if (northPiece == null || northPiece.isBlack()) {
            final Piece savePiece = northPiece;
            final Piece kingPiece = state.get(kingFile, 
                                              kingRank);

            state.set(kingFile, 
                      kingRank - 1, 
                      kingPiece);
            
            state.clear(kingFile, 
                        kingRank);

            // Once here, the north slot is either empty or is occupied by 
            // a black piece which can be possibly captured:
            WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(state, 
                                                   kingFile, 
                                                   kingRank - 1);
            
            if (WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES.file ==
                    CellCoordinates.NO_ATTACK_FILE) {
                
                // It is safe to move to north:
                state.set(kingFile, 
                          kingRank - 1,
                          savePiece);
                
                state.set(kingFile, 
                          kingRank,
                          kingPiece);
                
                return true;
            }
            
            // Once here, we have a north offender:
            addCopyCoordinateCells(
                    WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES);
            
            state.set(kingFile, 
                      kingRank - 1, 
                      savePiece);

            state.set(kingFile, 
                      kingRank,
                      kingPiece);
            
            // ..., that is, we cannot hide:
            return false;
        } 
        
        // Once here, northPiece is a white piece. King is blocked: 
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Tries to hide the white king to the south (towards the larger rank
     * index).
     * 
     * @param state    the state to investigate.
     * @param kingFile the file of the white king.
     * @param kingRank the rank of the white king.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the white king can hide by moving to 
     *         the south. 
     */
    private boolean canHideSouth(final ChessBoardState state, 
                                 final int kingFile, 
                                 final int kingRank) {
        if (kingRank == N - 1) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final Piece southPiece = state.get(kingFile, kingRank + 1);
        
        if (southPiece == null || southPiece.isBlack()) {
            
            final Piece savePiece = southPiece;
            final Piece kingPiece = state.get(kingFile, kingRank);

            state.set(kingFile,
                      kingRank + 1,
                      state.get(kingFile, 
                                kingRank));

            state.clear(kingFile, kingRank);

            // Once here, the south slot is either empty or is occupied by a
            // black piece which can be possibly captured:
            WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(state,
                                                   kingFile,
                                                   kingRank + 1);
            
            if (WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES.file == 
                    CellCoordinates.NO_ATTACK_FILE) {
                
                // It is safe to move to south:
                state.set(kingFile, 
                          kingRank + 1,
                          savePiece);
                
                state.set(kingFile,
                          kingRank, 
                          kingPiece);
                
                return true;
            } 
            
            // Once here, we have a south offender:
            addCopyCoordinateCells(
                    WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES);
            
            state.set(kingFile, 
                      kingRank + 1,
                      savePiece);
            
            state.set(kingFile,
                      kingRank, 
                      kingPiece);
            
            // ..., that is, we cannot hide:
            return false;
        }
        
        // Once here, southPiece is a white piece. King is blocked: 
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Tries to hide the white king to the west (towards the smaller file 
     * index).
     * 
     * @param state    the state to investigate.
     * @param kingFile the file of the white king.
     * @param kingRank the rank of the white king.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the white king can hide by moving to
     *         the west.
     */
    private boolean canHideWest(final ChessBoardState state, 
                                final int kingFile, 
                                final int kingRank) {
        if (kingFile == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final Piece westPiece = state.get(kingFile - 1, 
                                          kingRank);
        
        if (westPiece == null || westPiece.isBlack()) {

            final Piece savePiece = westPiece;
            final Piece kingPiece = state.get(kingFile,
                                              kingRank);
            state.set(kingFile - 1, 
                      kingRank, 
                      kingPiece);

            state.clear(kingFile,
                        kingRank);
            
            // Once here, the west slot is either empty or is occupied by a
            // black piece which can be possibly captured:
            WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(state, 
                                                   kingFile - 1, 
                                                   kingRank);
            
            if (WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES.file == 
                    CellCoordinates.NO_ATTACK_FILE) {
                
                // Once here, it is safe to move to the west.
                // First, undo the king move:
                state.set(kingFile - 1,
                          kingRank, 
                          savePiece);
                
                state.set(kingFile,
                          kingRank, 
                          kingPiece);
                
                // King move undone!
                return true;
            }
            
            // Once here, we have a west offender:
            addCopyCoordinateCells(
                    WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES);
            
            state.set(kingFile - 1, 
                      kingRank,
                      savePiece);
            
            state.set(kingFile,
                      kingRank, 
                      kingPiece);
            
            // ..., that is, we cannot hide:
            return false;
        }
        
        // Once here, westPiece is a white piece. King is blocked:
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Tries to hide the white king to the east (towards the larger file index).
     * 
     * @param state    the state to investigate.
     * @param kingFile the file of the white king.
     * @param kingRank the rank of the white king.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the white king can hide by moving to 
     *         the east.
     */
    private boolean canHideEast(final ChessBoardState state, 
                                final int kingFile, 
                                final int kingRank) {
        if (kingFile == N - 1) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final Piece eastPiece = state.get(kingFile + 1, kingRank);
        
        if (eastPiece == null || eastPiece.isBlack()) { 
            
            final Piece savePiece = eastPiece;
            final Piece kingPiece = state.get(kingFile, kingRank);

            state.set(kingFile + 1, 
                      kingRank,
                      state.get(kingFile, 
                                kingRank));

            state.clear(kingFile, kingRank);
            
            // Once here, the east slot is either empty or is occupied by a
            // black piece which can be possibly captured:
            WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(state, 
                                                   kingFile + 1, 
                                                   kingRank);
            
            if (WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES.file
                    == CellCoordinates.NO_ATTACK_FILE) {
                
                // It is safe to move to the east:
                state.set(kingFile + 1,
                          kingRank, 
                          savePiece);
                
                state.set(kingFile, 
                          kingRank, 
                          kingPiece);
                
                return true;
            }
            
            // Once here, we have an east offender:
            addCopyCoordinateCells(
                    WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES);
            
            state.set(kingFile + 1, 
                      kingRank, 
                      savePiece);
            
            state.set(kingFile, 
                      kingRank, 
                      kingPiece);
            
            // ..., that is, we cannot hide:
            return false;
        }
        
        // Once here, eastPiece is a white piece. King is blocked:
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Tries to hide the white king to the north west (towards the smaller file 
     * index and the smaller rank index).
     * 
     * @param state    the state to investigate.
     * @param kingFile the file of the white king.
     * @param kingRank the rank of the white king.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the white king can hide by moving to 
     *         the north west.
     */
    private boolean canHideNorthWest(final ChessBoardState state, 
                                     final int kingFile, 
                                     final int kingRank) {
        if (kingFile == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (kingRank == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final Piece northWestPiece = state.get(kingFile - 1, 
                                               kingRank - 1);
        
        
        if (northWestPiece == null || northWestPiece.isBlack()) {
            
            final Piece savePiece = northWestPiece;
            final Piece kingPiece = state.get(kingFile, 
                                              kingRank);
            state.set(kingFile - 1,
                      kingRank - 1, 
                      kingPiece);

            state.clear(kingFile, 
                        kingRank);
            
            // Once here, the north west slot is either empty or is occupied by 
            // a black piece which can be possibly captured:
            WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(state, 
                                                   kingFile - 1,
                                                   kingRank - 1);
            
            if (WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES.file == 
                    CellCoordinates.NO_ATTACK_FILE) {
                
                // It is safe to move to the west:
                state.set(kingFile - 1,
                          kingRank - 1, 
                          savePiece);
                
                state.set(kingFile,
                          kingRank,
                          kingPiece);
                
                return true;
            }
            
            // Once here, we have a north west offender:
            addCopyCoordinateCells(
                    WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES);
            
            state.set(kingFile - 1,
                      kingRank - 1, 
                      savePiece);
            
            state.set(kingFile,
                      kingRank,
                      kingPiece);
            
            // ..., that is, we cannot hide:
            return false;
        }
        
        // Once here, northWestPiece is a white piece. King is blocked:
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Tries to hide the white king to the east west (towards the larger file 
     * index and the smaller rank index).
     * 
     * @param state    the state to investigate.
     * @param kingFile the file of the white king.
     * @param kingRank the rank of the white king.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the white king can hide by moving to
     *         the north east.
     */
    private boolean canHideNorthEast(final ChessBoardState state, 
                                     final int kingFile, 
                                     final int kingRank) {
        if (kingFile == N - 1) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (kingRank == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final Piece northEastPiece = state.get(kingFile + 1, 
                                               kingRank - 1);
        
        if (northEastPiece == null || northEastPiece.isBlack()) {

            final Piece savePiece = northEastPiece;
            final Piece kingPiece = state.get(kingFile,
                                              kingRank);

            state.set(kingFile + 1, 
                      kingRank - 1,
                      kingPiece);

            state.clear(kingFile, 
                        kingRank);
            
            // Once here, the north east slot is either empty or is occupied by 
            // a black piece which can be possibly captured:
            WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(state, 
                                                   kingFile + 1, 
                                                   kingRank - 1);
            
            if (WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES.file == 
                    CellCoordinates.NO_ATTACK_FILE) {
                
                // It is safe to move to the west:
                state.set(kingFile + 1, 
                          kingRank - 1,
                          savePiece);
                
                state.set(kingFile,
                          kingRank,
                          kingPiece);
                
                return true;
            }
            
            // Once here, we have a west offender:
            addCopyCoordinateCells(
                    WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES);
            
            state.set(kingFile + 1, 
                      kingRank - 1, 
                      savePiece);

            state.set(kingFile,
                      kingRank,
                      kingPiece);
            
            // ..., that is, we cannot hide:
            return false;
        }
        
        // Once here, northEastPiece is a white piece. King is blocked:
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Tries to hide the white king to the south west (towards the smaller file
     * index and towards the larger rank index).'
     * 
     * @param state    the state to investigate.
     * @param kingFile the file of the white king.
     * @param kingRank the rank of the white king.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the white king can hide by moving to
     *         to the south west.
     */
    private boolean canHideSouthWest(final ChessBoardState state, 
                                     final int kingFile, 
                                     final int kingRank) {
        if (kingFile == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (kingRank == N - 1) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final Piece southWestPiece = state.get(kingFile - 1, 
                                               kingRank + 1);
        
        
        if (southWestPiece == null || southWestPiece.isBlack()) {
            
            final Piece savePiece = southWestPiece;
            final Piece kingPiece = state.get(kingFile,
                                              kingRank);

            state.set(kingFile - 1, 
                      kingRank + 1, 
                      kingPiece);

            state.clear(kingFile,
                        kingRank);
            
            // Once here, the south west slot is either empty or is occupied by
            // a black piece which can be possibly captured:
            WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(state, 
                                                   kingFile - 1, 
                                                   kingRank + 1);
            
            if (WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES.file == 
                    CellCoordinates.NO_ATTACK_FILE) {
                
                // It is safe to move to the west:
                state.set(kingFile - 1, 
                          kingRank + 1,
                          savePiece);
                
                state.set(kingFile, 
                          kingRank, 
                          kingPiece);
                
                return true;
            }
            
            // Once here, we have a west offender:
            addCopyCoordinateCells(
                    WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES);
            
            state.set(kingFile - 1, 
                      kingRank + 1, 
                      savePiece);

            state.set(kingFile, 
                      kingRank, 
                      kingPiece);
            
            // ..., that is, we cannot hide:
            return false;
        }
        
        // Once here, southWestPiece is a white piece. King is blocked:
        return false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Tries to hide the white king to the south east (towards the larger file 
     * and rank indices).
     * 
     * @param state    the state to investigate.
     * @param kingFile the file of the white king.
     * @param kingRank the rank of the white king.
     * 
     * @return {@code true} if and only if the white king can hide by moving to
     *         the south east.
     */
    private boolean canHideSouthEast(final ChessBoardState state, 
                                     final int kingFile, 
                                     final int kingRank) {
        if (kingFile == N - 1) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (kingRank == N - 1) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final Piece southEastPiece = state.get(kingFile + 1,
                                               kingRank + 1);
        
        if (southEastPiece == null || southEastPiece.isBlack()) {

            final Piece savePiece = southEastPiece;
            final Piece kingPiece = state.get(kingFile, 
                                              kingRank);
            state.set(kingFile + 1,
                      kingRank + 1, 
                      kingPiece);

            state.clear(kingFile,
                        kingRank);
            
            // Once here, the south east slot is either empty or is occupied by 
            // a black piece which can be possibly captured:
            WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.check(state, 
                                                   kingFile + 1, 
                                                   kingRank + 1);
            
            if (WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES.file == 
                    CellCoordinates.NO_ATTACK_FILE) {
                
                // It is safe to move to south east:
                state.set(kingFile + 1,
                          kingRank + 1, 
                          savePiece);
                
                state.set(kingFile,
                          kingRank, 
                          kingPiece);
                
                return true;
            }
            
            // Once here, we have a west offender:
            addCopyCoordinateCells(
                    WHITE_PIECE_UNDER_ATTACK_CHECKER.ATTACKER_COORDINATES);
            
            state.set(kingFile + 1,
                      kingRank + 1, 
                      savePiece);
            
            state.set(kingFile,
                      kingRank, 
                      kingPiece);
            
            // ..., that is, we cannot hide:
            return false;
        }
           
        // Once here, southEastPiece is a white piece. King is blocked: 
        return false;
    }
    
    private void addCopyCoordinateCells(final CellCoordinates cellCoordinates) {
        ATTACKER_CELLS[attackerCellsSize].file = cellCoordinates.file;
        ATTACKER_CELLS[attackerCellsSize].rank = cellCoordinates.rank;
        attackerCellsSize++;
    }
}

Critique request
I would love to receive arbitrary commentary. However, I am most concerned with the following issue:

Is there any bugs?
Could the code be made more readable?
How would I make it run faster?


Forgive me if I am blind, but I don't see checking for an interference option. Consider a test case: White: K a1, R b1, p a2; Black: B c3. King cannot escape, Bishop cannot be captured, and yet it is not a checkmate: White can interfere with Rb2.

Be color blind
If you have a WhiteCheckMateInspector that means you will also need a BlackCheckMateInspector. But what's the difference really? Colors. Just make one class that can handle both scenarios by taking a simple Color parameter.
Be direction blind
You have duplicated code for all eight different directions:
canHideWest, canHideEast, canHideNorth, canHideNorthWest,
canHideNorthEast, canHideSouth, canHideSouthWest, canHideSouthEast.
Instead write one method canHideAt and iterate through the eight different directions (I would recommend writing an enum for this, with X and Y values of 1/0/-1).
Mutating global state
Your private static final CellCoordinates[] ATTACKER_CELLS is static and is being mutated, which means that you'll never be able to have two instances active at the same time without a whole lot of bugs.
A different approach
You have previously posted questions about finding possible moves in Chess. If you would just iterate through all possible moves and check (pun possibly intended) if the color being checked is still in check, then that's not a possible move. If the player is in check and has no valid move, then that's checkmate.
Test-cases
There are three ways to get out of a check:

Take the attacking piece (not possible if it's a double-check)
Put something in the attacking path to cover your king (also not possible if it's double-check)
Move the king.

I would strongly recommend writing test-cases to make sure that you cover all of these scenarios.

Lack of readability
The following fields and methods are unclear to me and could either be named differently, or their purpose documented (or possibly both):

addCopyCoordinateCells
private static final int ATTACKER_CELLS_LENGTH
private static final CellCoordinates[] ATTACKER_CELLS
private int attackerCellsSize

Additionally, I would recommend changing cannotDefend to canDefend to avoid unexepected negations.

Another test case might be to test whether it returns false as you might expect in case of a stalemate (no moves at all are possible, not even moves that keep the current player in check).  At the very least, it would be a good idea to document what the expected result is when called on a stalemate position.

Violation of SRP
You said that WhiteCheckMateInspector has the following responsibility:

This class implements the API for checking for checkmate

So it supposed to answer the question if the current position is checkmate or not.
But, it turns out that under the hood isInCheckMate() changes positions of pieces on the board. Why complicating this class by assigning this additional responsibility of modifying the board state?
This makes it harder to understand the code and impedes testing (because testing with side-effects is painful). Consider introducing a separate abstraction for that matter.
I doubt that you need two classes (and interface), to implement the required logic. Just don't hard-code isBlack() checks, work with instance fields.
Missing domain-specific names and actions
I've already pointed at this issue in the answer to your previous question.
Domain-specific behavior is described through combinations of get/set-style methods:

child.clear() + child.set() - for moving a piece
child.set() + child.set() - for capturing an enemy's piece

Such code does not communicate properly what it's meant to do. I'll be cleaner if the board was exposing methods move() and capture() instead.
Also checks like this northPiece == null || northPiece.isBlack() can be performed by the board if we introduce methods like canMove(), canCapture() so that the code dialing with the board will use a more expressive behavior instead of low-level logic.
